# A concise Putnam linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, convex-hulls

This is a Putnam practice problem a friend gives me:

Show that diagonal $(A_{11}, A_{22},...,A_{nn})$ of a symmetric matrix $A_{n \times n}$ lies in convex hull defined by all $n!$ permutation of $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n $ where $\lambda_i $ are eigenvalues of $A$.

I am literally without a clue. I think this has to do with sum of diagonal being sum of eigenvalues but not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: These ingredients might be useful: since $A$ is symmetric, there is an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^t$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues, and $P^t$ is the transpose of $P$, which is also the inverse of $P$. You can work out what $PD$ looks like, and then what $PDP^t$ looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Lambda$ be a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ of $A$, and let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix such that $A = U\Lambda U^T$. We find that
$$
A_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^n u_{ij}^2\cdot \lambda_j .
$$
There are several ways to go from there, but the standard way to proceed is to apply the [Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) or something like it.

Comment: Are you sure Birkhoff can be applied here? I don't see anything bistochastic around.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What about the matrix $M$ with $m_{ij} = u_{ij}^2$?

Comment: Oh, you are right! For some reason I thought the rows wouldnt be unit-length.